# escape hashs (#) passed as argument to use them in inner macro

Tags: macros, xparse, nesting, parameters

I am using nested macros using the `xparse` package, my ultimate goal being to have a custom macro factory. I have simplified my current problem here.

I want to give a pattern as an argument, like in this example:

```tex
\DeclareDocumentCommand\Foo{O{\emph{##1}} O{dummy} m}{{%
    \def\@style##1{#1}%
    \@style{#3}%
}}
Hello \Foo{world}!
This is \Foo[\color{blue}\textbf{#1}]{nice}!
```

> [image: compiled LaTeX]

However, if I add one level of nesting, everything breaks:

```tex
\NewDocumentCommand\DeclareFoo{O{\emph{##1}}}{%
    \DeclareDocumentCommand\Foo{O{dummy} m}{{%
        \def\@style####1{#1}%
        \@style{##2}%
    }}%
}
\DeclareFoo% gets the #1 of \Foo instead of \@style
Hello \Foo{world}!
\DeclareFoo[\color{blue}\textbf{#1}]% same
This is \Foo{nice}!
\DeclareFoo[\color{red}\textbf{##1}]% this works but I would rather use only one "#"
This is \Foo{not nice}!
```

> [image: compiled LaTeX]

`\DeclareFoo` is supposed to be a black box, and the user is not supposed to guess the number of nesting levels (please do not mark [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42463/what-is-the-meaning-of-double-pound-symbol-number-sign-hash-character-1-in) as a duplicate).

Is there a way to escape the `#` inside `#1` argument?
I tried `\StrSubstitute` from the `xstring` package to double the number of `#` in `#1`,
but couldn't make it work...

Comment: Related question: [macros - Prevent hash doubling with \message - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520388/prevent-hash-doubling-with-message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case there are some "workarounds":

- In case you can tolerate some "global namespace pollution" you can do this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\DeclareFoo{O{\emph{##1}}}{%
    \def\@foo@helper@style##1{#1}%
    \DeclareDocumentCommand\Foo{O{dummy} m}{%
        \@foo@helper@style{##2}%
    }%
}%


\DeclareFoo% gets the #1 of \Foo instead of \@style
Hello \Foo{world}!
\DeclareFoo[\color{blue}\textbf{#1}]%
This is \Foo{nice}!
\DeclareFoo[\color{red}\textbf{#1}]%
This is \Foo{not nice}!

\end{document}
```

As long as the helper macro's name is "sufficiently unique" it should not be a problem.

- As a alternative solution you can "pass" the content through the macro definition by storing it in an macro/token register:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\DeclareFoo{O{\emph{##1}}}{
    \tl_set:Nn \@foo@helper@body {#1}
    \DeclareDocumentCommand\Foo{O{dummy} m}{
        \group_begin:
        \exp_args:NnV \use:n {\def\@foo@helper@style####1} \@foo@helper@body
        \@foo@helper@style{##2}
        \group_end:
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\DeclareFoo% gets the #1 of \Foo instead of \@style
Hello \Foo{world}!
\DeclareFoo[\color{blue}\textbf{#1}]%
This is \Foo{nice}!
\DeclareFoo[\color{red}\textbf{#1}]%
This is \Foo{not nice}!

\end{document}
```

The `\exp_args:NnV \use:n` is a bit ugly, but basically it executes the `def` with the variable as its "body".

Answer (score 2):

For comparison: what we need to do in OpTeX:

```
\fontfam[lm]

\def\Foodeclared{}
\optdef\DeclareFoo[]{\ea\def \ea\Foodeclared \ea{\the\opt}}
\optdef\Foo[]#1{{\em \Foodeclared \the\opt #1}}

\DeclareFoo
Hello, \Foo{world}!

Hello, \Foo[\bf]{world}!

\DeclareFoo[\Blue\bf]%
This is \Foo{nice}!

\DeclareFoo[\Red\bf]%
Is this \Foo{nice, too}?

Is this \Foo[\Green\caps\rm]{nice, too}?

Is this \Foo{nice, too}?

\bye
```

The result is the same as in the Ulrich's answer.

Comment: +1 - With your laconic way of making things clear, you once more made my day. ;-)  I really need to take an intensive look at OpTeX. I assume things are implemented more efficiently/better there than I am used to do.

Comment: This answer is "cheating" in that it workarounds the issue of doubling `#` completely by having suitable macros (in this case `\bf` instead of `\textbf`, which applies until the end of the group) in order to make passing `#` unnecessary (but sure, it works, no problem there.)

Answer (score 1):

With the `\DeclareFoo` definition, the default optional argument must have an extra pair of `#` tokens: `O{\emph{####1}}`, in order to make the default `\emph` case work.  Nonetheless, even here, you still need to use the `##1` notation when specifying a separate optional argument,  as in `\DeclareFoo[\color{red}\textbf{##1}]`, because `##1` is required in `\DeclareFoo` to act as `#1` in a subsequent invocation of `\Foo`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\Foo{O{\emph{##1}} O{dummy} m}{{%
    \def\@style##1{#1}%
    \@style{#3}%
}}
Hello \Foo{world}!
This is \Foo[\color{blue}\textbf{#1}]{nice}!

\NewDocumentCommand\DeclareFoo{O{\emph{####1}}}{%
    \DeclareDocumentCommand\Foo{O{dummy} m}{{%
        \def\@style####1{#1}%
        \@style{##2}%
    }}%
}
\DeclareFoo% works
Hello \Foo{world}!
\DeclareFoo[\color{red}\textbf{##1}]% this works but I would rather use only one "#"
This is \Foo{required}!

\DeclareFoo[\color{blue}\textbf{#1}]% gets the #1 of \Foo instead of \@style
This \Foo{would be nice, but} doesn't work because \#\#1 is needed 
  in DeclareFoo to produce \#1 in Foo!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there absolutely no way of "programmatically" double the number of `#` inside of DeclareFoo?

Comment: @User9123 I hesitate to make an *absolute* statement, for there may be someone of greater skill who can accomplish it...but, for the moment, it is beyond my ken.

Comment: I have the impression it should be achievable, some other commands accept arguments with single hashes (`\titleformat`, or `\DeclareDocumentCommand` itself, to name a few... are these even defined in pure latex?). But I am lacking the skills to understand how they did it.

Comment: @User9123 The one technique I have used (though I don't know how to apply it in your situation) is `\def\a{\def\b##1}`.  This allows one to say `\a{Here is #1}` with the result being `\def\b#1{Here is #1}`.  In this case a single hash `#1` is passed as an argument to `\a`, which defines a separate macro `\b`.

Comment: Yes, I have used that technique in the first example (but I am calling `\b` directly inside of `\a`). Which makes me think that in the second example, if I move `\def\@style` in `\DeclareFoo` instead of `\Foo`, the second example is suddenly working.

Comment: But then, `\@style` is not a local macro anymore. This is an issue, especially because my goal is to create a function factory, i.e., `\DeclareFoo` is supposed to take the name of the declared macro as an argument. If there is only one `\@style` function, this means that each created macros would have the same style. But I want each created macro to have a distinct style. I might try to create a `\@style@Foo` macro instead, where `Foo` is replaced by the name of the created function. I am still wondering if it is possible to declare `\@style` as a local macro...

Comment: @User9123 Commands like `\titleformat` and `\DeclareDocumentCommand` don't need to perform hash-doubling with their arguments: At the time when these commands are carried out and their arguments are grabbed and delivered in a mix with the replacement-text, the stuff delivered does not form a second-level-definition/definition nested inside another definition (whose hashes would need to be doubled) but a first-level-definition/a definition not nested within another definition.

Answer (score 0):

**Ad "programmatically double the number of #":**

The discussions

[How to have hashes doubled *and* things expanded?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/509697/118714)

and

[Double hashes inside macro definition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/552998/118714)

might be of interest to you.

There you find approaches to the matter using **l3regex** or taking advantage of the fact that things like `\write` and `\scantokens` double hashes.

For the sake of having fun I did my own thing with the code below.

---

For recent TeX engines where `\detokenize` of the ε-TeX extensions is available I can offer a routine `\ReplicateEveryHash` which can serve as a workaround in some situations.

Syntax of the routine `\ReplicateEveryHash` is

`\ReplicateEveryHash{⟨number⟩}{⟨balanced text⟩}`

The routine `\ReplicateEveryHash` by means of `\romannumeral`-expansion recursively replicates *⟨number⟩* times every explicit character token of category 6(parameter) that is contained in the *⟨balanced text⟩*.

The gist of the check for a hash is: `\string#` delivers a single hash-character-token of category 12(other) while with `\detokenize` hash-doubling takes place and therefore `\detokenize{#}` delivers two hash-character-tokens of category 12(other). (The edge case of an explicit space character of category 6 needs separate treatment.)

In case the *⟨balanced text⟩*-argument of `\ReplicateEveryHash` contains matching pairs of explicit character tokens of category 1(begin group) and 2(end group), each of these pairs triggers another level of `\romannumeral`-expansion. Therefore **excessive nesting of braces within the *⟨balanced text⟩*-argument of `\ReplicateEveryHash` will take its toll on the semantic nest**.

**Besides this `\ReplicateEveryHash` does replace matching pairs of explicit character tokens of category 1(begin group) and 2(end group) of the *⟨balanced text⟩*-argument by matching pairs of opening curly braces of category 1 and closing curly braces of category 2.**
*I suppose this won't be a problem in most situations as usually the curly braces are the only characters of category 1/2.*
*But this must be mentioned because this means that `\ReplicateEveryHash` is suitable only for situations where replacing explicit begin-grouping-character-tokens and explicit end-grouping-character-tokens by explicit curly-brace-tokens of the same kind doesn't matter.*

**Caveats/possible pitfalls:**

If you place `\ReplicateEveryHash{2}{...}` into an `\edef`, due to `\romannumeral`-expansion hash-doubling will—in contrast with the `\edef\macro{\unexpanded\expandafter{\expanded{#1}}}`-approach—take place *before* expanding the tokens that form the *⟨balanced text⟩*-argument of `\ReplicateEveryHash`.  Therefore `\edef\macro{\ReplicateEveryHash{2}{\string#1}}` (or `\ReplicateEveryHash{2}{\edef\macro{\string#1}}` if you prefer) will yield an error-message about an illegal parameter number because in the hash-doubling-step you will get two hashes trailed by the digit `1`. The first hash will be stringified. The second hash, which is trailed by the digit `1`, will not be stringified and therefore will be taken for a parameter `#1` while the `⟨parameter text⟩` of `\macro` is empty.

```latex
\makeatletter
%%//////////////  Begin of code for \ReplicateEveryHash  //////////////////////
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%%    \UD@stopromannumeral, 
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,
%%    \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange, \UD@removespace
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull, \UD@CheckWhetherBrace,
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace, \UD@replicate, \UD@ExtractFirstArg
%%=============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@removespace{\UD@firstoftwo{\def\UD@removespace}{} {}}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is an explicit character of
%% category 1:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has a leading
%%                        explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked does not have a
%%                        leading explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with an explicit space-token:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does have a
%%                                       leading explicit space-token>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does not have a
%%                                       a leading explicit space-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
      \string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB.#1 }{}%
    }{}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB{%
  \long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB#1 {%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
    {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
     \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
  }%
}%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \UD@replicate{<number>}{<tokens>}
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@replicateloop[3]{%
  \if m#3\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\fi
  {\UD@replicateloop{#1}{#2#1}}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@replicate[2]{%
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}%
                                      {\UD@replicateloop{#2}{}}\relax
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{ABCDE} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{{AB}CDE} yields  {AB}
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral-expansion the result is delivered after two 
%% expansion-steps/after "hitting" \UD@ExtractFirstArg with \expandafter
%% twice.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument must not be blank.
%% This case can be cranked out via \UD@CheckWhetherBlank before calling
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg.
%%
%% Use frozen-\relax as delimiter for speeding things up.
%% I chose frozen-\relax because David Carlisle pointed out in
%% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578877>
%% that frozen-\relax cannot be (re)defined in terms of \outer and cannot be
%% affected by \uppercase/\lowercase.
%%
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg's argument may contain frozen-\relax:
%% The only effect is that internally more iterations are needed for
%% obtaining the result.
%%
%%.............................................................................
\@ifdefinable\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}%
  {\long\def\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1#2}{{#1}}%
}%
\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter
  \UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\romannumeral
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@Exchange
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\ifnum0=0\fi}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  }{%
    \UD@stopromannumeral\romannumeral\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop
  }%
}{%
  \newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArg[1]%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillFrozenrelax#1}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% \ReplicateEveryHash{<number>}{<balanced text>}%
%%
%%   Each explicit category-6(parameter)-character-token of the 
%%   <balanced text> is replicated <number> times.
%%
%%   You obtain the result after two expansion-steps, i.e., 
%%   in expansion-contexts you get the result after "hitting" 
%%   \ReplicateEveryHash by two \expandafter.
%%   
%%   As a side-effect, the routine does replace matching pairs of explicit
%%   character tokens of catcode 1 and 2 by matching pairs of curly braces
%%   of catcode 1 and 2.
%%   I suppose this won't be a problem in most situations as usually the
%%   curly braces are the only characters of category code 1 / 2...
%%
%%   This routine needs \detokenize from the eTeX extensions.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\ReplicateEveryHash[2]{%
   \romannumeral
   \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
   \romannumeral\number\number#1 000}{%
     \UD@ReplicateEveryHashLoop{#2}{}%
   }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ReplicateEveryHashLoop[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@stopromannumeral#2}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{#1}{%
       \expandafter\UD@ReplicateEveryHashLoop
       \expandafter{\UD@removespace#1}{#2 }{#3}%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#1}{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
            \romannumeral%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@ReplicateEveryHashLoop
            \UD@ExtractFirstArg{#1}{}{#3}%
        }{#2}}%
        {\expandafter\UD@ReplicateEveryHashLoop
         \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
        }{#3}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherHash
        \UD@ExtractFirstArg{#1}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherHash[4]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace\expandafter{\string#1}{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\UD@removespace\string#1}{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\UD@removespace\detokenize{#1}}{%
        % something whose stringification yields a single space
        \UD@secondoftwo
      }{% explicit space of catcode 6
        \UD@firstoftwo
      }%
    }{% something whose stringification has a leading space
      \UD@secondoftwo
    }%
  }{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo
    \expandafter{\expandafter}\string#1}{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo
      \expandafter{\expandafter}\detokenize{#1}}{%
        % no hash
        \UD@secondoftwo
      }{% hash
        \UD@firstoftwo
      }%
    }{% no hash
      \UD@secondoftwo
    }%
  }%
  {% hash
    \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
    \expandafter{%
      \romannumeral\expandafter
      \UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral\UD@replicateloop{#1}{}#4\relax
      }{\UD@stopromannumeral#3}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@ReplicateEveryHashLoop
      \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}%
    }%
  }{% no hash
    \expandafter\UD@ReplicateEveryHashLoop
    \expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}{#3#1}%
  }{#4}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%%//////////////  End of code for \ReplicateEveryHash  ////////////////////////
\makeatother




\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\DeclareFoo{O{\emph{##1}}}{%
    % \DeclareFoo's #1 denotes the tokens that form 
    % \Foo's default-definition-text of the macro
    % \@style.
    % At the time of carrying out \DeclareFoo the
    % definition-text of \@style is a second-level-
    % definition where hashes of macro-parameters need
    % to be doubled.  
    % Therefore hashes in \DeclareFoo's #1, which denotes
    % a possible definition-text of \@style, need to be
    % doubled, otherwise the user has to do so when
    % specifying a non-default value for \DeclareFoo's
    % optional argument/a non-default definition-text for
    % the second-level-definition of \@style.
    \ReplicateEveryHash{2}{\DeclareDocumentCommand\Foo{O{#1} m}}{{%
        \def\@style####1{##1}%
        \@style{##2}%
    }}%
    % The following might be better for keeping the
    % definition of \@style local because \@style isn't
    % (re)defined any more when its replacement-text is
    % carried out:
    % \ReplicateEveryHash{2}{\DeclareDocumentCommand\Foo{O{#1} m}}{{%
    %     \begingroup
    %     \def\@style####1{\endgroup##1}%
    %     \@style{##2}%
    % }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\DeclareFoo
Hello, \Foo{world}!

Hello, \Foo[\textbf{#1}]{world}!

\DeclareFoo[\color{blue}\textbf{#1}]%
This is \Foo{nice}!

\DeclareFoo[\color{red}\textbf{#1}]%
Is this \Foo{nice, too}?

Is this \Foo[\color[named]{ForestGreen}\textsc{#1}]{nice, too}?

Is this \Foo{nice, too}?

\end{document}
```

[image]